# apt-get won't handle package locking made in Synaptic

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

In Synaptic I locked skype to version 2.2.0.35 and the package manager is correctly ignoring newer version (it doesn't select skype upgrade).

On the contrary, apt-get upgrade will propose the upgrade.

I know I could lock the package with `echo "skype hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`, but I'd like to have Synaptic changes being reflected in apt-get

Comment: mat be apt-get doesn't have this option ? I am not expert but it seems apt-get and dpkg are 2 different commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally turned into a whish in Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692017

Answer (score 3):

Synaptic has it's own configuration file, separate from dpgk's so this will be a manual process. However, here are some commands that should make things easier.

To put the pinned Synaptic packages on hold:

```
sed -n '/Package:/h;/Pin:/{g;s/\(Package: \)//;s/.*/& hold/p}' < /var/lib/synaptic/preferences |  sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

If you want to change the held packages back to install:

```
dpkg --get-selections |sed -n '/hold/H;s/hold/install/p'| sudo dpkg --set-selections
```